# (Vue.js) How to use onClick event in SweetAlert2

Tags: vue.js, sweetalert2

```
axios
  .get(apiUrl)
  .then(response => {
    this.$swal.fire({
      html: response.data.data.schools
              .map(item => `<div onclick="onClick(this)">${item.school_name}</div>`)
              .join('')
    })
  })
```

I want to use onclick event in SweetAlert2.

I used this code, but an error occurred.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: onClick is not defined
>       at HTMLDivElement.onclick

How can I use onclick event??
Help me!

Comment: Did you defined `onClick` function?

Answer (score 0):

It show, on you current `HTMLDOM`there was no function defined as `onClick`. You have to define a function named `onClick` and its functionality first.

for vue:

you have to define the function inside vue instance methods.

Define target:

```
axios
  .get(apiUrl)
  .then(response => {
    this.$swal.fire({
      target: document.getElementById('app'),
      html: response.data.data.schools
              .map(item => `<div onclick="onClick(this)">${item.school_name}</div>`)
              .join('')
    })
  })
```

Comment: I defined 'onClick' function in App.vue. Also the above code in methods for App.vue. But the error occurred.

Comment: the function should defined in methods.

Comment: I defined the function in methods. The methods in App.vue, onClick, SweetAlert2 function.

Comment: inspect your swal. it is outside from your vue instance.

Comment: I just wrote down that code to make it easier to see. Swal is on the methods for App.vue.

Comment: try to target on a div `target: document.getElementById('app')`.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: onClick is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Comment: I think define onClick in index.html, function is work. The contents of the 'html' appear to be unmanageable in Vue.